# How to hide the div below the current dropdown list when other is selected - qualtrics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototypejs, qualtrics

I am trying to make a survey in Qualtrics using custom JS so that Question 1 has a dropdown list that has multiple options in it, the last one being 'Others' I am trying to make it so that when Question 1 has 'Others' selected Question 2 will hide and not be shown anymore. I have previewed the survey and gotten the ID's of the div elements and dropdown as:

Dropdown ID = QR~QID12
Div I want to hide ID = QID119

I have been trying with this code below but have not had it working yet

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
    this.questionclick = function(event,element){

         if (this.getTextValue() == 'Others'){
           $('QID119').show();
           alert('show');
         } else if (this.getTextValue() != 'Others'&&this.getTextValue() != '')  {
            $('QID119').hide();
            alert('hide');
        }
    }

});
```

I have tried with this.getTextValue() as well as $("QR~QID12").getValue() but neither seems to hide the div below it.

Answer (score 1):

A few things: (1) The question is not the select, so your code is looking at the wrong element (this.questionclick); (2) The question isn't a choice either (this.getTextValue), so again your code is looking at the wrong element; (3) A click handler is not a good choice for a select. Also, your code does the opposite show/hide of what you wrote. Finally, it is best to avoid using fixed QID codes.

Try the following. I'm guessing you want what you wrote for show/hide, but if not, just change the condition:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
    var nq = $(this.questionId).next('.QuestionOuter');     //next question
    var select = $(this.questionId).down('select');         //select element
    hideShow(select);   //initialize to support prev button
    select.on('change', function() {
            hideShow(this); 
    });

    function hideShow(selEl) {
        var selText = selEl.options[selEl.selectedIndex].text;
        if (selText == 'Others' || selText == '') nq.hide();
        else nq.show();
        selEl.blur();
    }

});
```